# 2 basic Textmate shortcuts 'don't save' and 'replace all'

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

Ok, maybe they're system shortcuts. I've googled (just a bit) and couldn't find an answer. Maybe there isn't any :) Still..

I love keyboard and I use quite a few in TextMate but just realise I still use the mouse for **2 of the most common actions**:

- How do I press **search and replace** after the S/R dialog box is up? - if you press enter it just takes you to the next occurrence of the search string
- when I close a file that I don't want to save, how can I choose **don't save** without touching the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search and replace (actually it's called "Replace & Find") shortcut is **alt-cmd-f** and works both inside the Find dialog and without it. With using other shortcuts like **cmd-f**, **shift-cmd-f**, **cmd-G** you can perform most of the search/replace actions without even opening the dialog. For example, if you want to perform the substitution, you press **alt-cmd-f**, then another is highlighted and if you want to skip it, it's **cmd-G**, which finds yet another, and so on.

As for the second question, I think it's a general Mac OS X issue -- the message boxes buttons don't have keyboard shortcuts in other apps, too. When I first switched from Windows, this annoyed me but I got used to it by now.

Comment: thanks!
I have figured out the second question (not by myself, I've asked the same on superuser :)

it's **⌘+D** as in don't save, and it's system wide. And that helps :)

Comment: Oh and for switching from Windows.. I've been frustrated there are no Alt + letter shortcuts for reaching the menu bar items.. found an alternative:  
  go System Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse > Keyboard Shortcuts > Keyboard Navigation - if that's turned on (**⌃F1**) you can reach the menu bar with **⌃F2**  
  You can also **move between dialog boxes' buttons** (I forgot about that) with **⌃F7** - that would have solved my second question - but not the handiest key combination.

Answer (score 3):

To select Don't Save from the keyboard, you can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. (This works in most OS X apps, not just TextMate.)

Answer (score 1):

I recently built a web site to store lists of shortcut keys and there is a great list of TextMate Shortcut Keys for Mac on there.

If you know any more you can add them yourself too!

Here's the link http://shortcutkeys.org/software-shortcuts/mac/textmate

Answer (score 1):

If you want to choose the answer for any dialog with the keyboard, go to "System Preferences" > "Keyboard" > "Keyboard Shortcuts". On the bottom of that page there are two radio buttons. Activate "All controls". Now you can switch options of a dialog box with the tab key in every proper OS X application. Note that this is a secondary option, thus you can hit the enter key for the default behaviour or space to trigger your secondary option. Most often it's set to the opposite of the default behaviour, i.e. "Don't save" in a file save dialog and "no" or "cancel" in many many other applications.

I think thats a great feature. Due to the secondary option I always hit either enter or space, depending which option I wanted.